# Multi-line text padding

Tags: html, css

I have a following structure:

```
<div class="1">
  <div class="2">
    2.
  </div>
  <div class="3">
    3.
  </div>
  <div class="4">
    very long line of text
  </div>
</div>
```

So `div` 1 has `display: block`, all the others have `display: inline`. **My goal** is to make this very long line of text being displayed like that:

```
2. 3. very long
      line of text
```

If I try making `div` 4 an `inline-block` or `inline-flex` and set `margin` and `text-indent` properties, then it kinda does what I want, but it also moves whole text down one line like this:

```
2. 3. 
very long
      line of text
```

How do I do that properly?

Comment: Make 1 a flex container

Comment: @Huangism same result

Comment: Please see my answer and fiddle

Comment: Your class values are invalid in CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B their actual names are different, that's just for simplification purpose, but thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex to solve this, make the container div display flex.

Make sure your classes start with a letter ([Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors))

https://jsfiddle.net/cymozzeL/1/

```
.t1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

There is a lot more you can do with this, please have a look at

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `display: flex` for compatibility reasons with older browsers, you can make them inline-blocks, align them vertically at the top and then use jQuery to get their widths and calculate the width of DIV4:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var width1 = $(".x1").innerWidth();
var width2 = $(".x2").innerWidth();
var width3 = $(".x3").innerWidth();
var width4 = (width1 - width2 - width3 - 8) + "px";
$(".x4").css("width", width4);
});
```

```css
.x2, .x3, .x4 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x1">
  <div class="x2">
    2.
  </div>
  <div class="x3">
    3.
  </div>
  <div class="x4">
    very long line of text very long line of text very long line of text very long line of text very long line of text very long line of text very long line of text
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: The `-8` in the calculation is done by trial and error - it's necessary because of some whitespace created by the linebreaks in the HTML code which otherwise would break DIV4 into the next line)

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately, I have to use pure css